# How to show that orthogonal group is generated by rotations and permutations?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, rotations

How to show that orthogonal group is generated by rotations and permutations? Rotations are of the form $\begin{bmatrix}R&0\\0&I\end{bmatrix}$, where $R$ is $\begin{bmatrix}\cos\alpha&-\sin\alpha\\ \sin \alpha&\cos\alpha\end{bmatrix}$. Is there any reference on this?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint.* To begin, think about how you can eliminate all but one entries on the first column by left-multiplying the matrix by Givens rotations.

Comment: I know how to do this. Now suppose that I have simplified the first column to $e_1$, I then want to simplify the second column to $e_2$, but how would I guarantee that it would not affect the first column?

Comment: @joseph Here is another hint: after eliminating all other entries on the first column, what will the remaining entry become? And what will the other entries on the same row become?